# Count combinations of a given partition

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Suppose we have a partition $(n_1,\ldots,n_k)$ with $n_i\geq1$ of a given positive
number $n$, that is $n_1+\cdots+n_k=n$. How many compositions 
$(n_1',\ldots,n_k')$ are there, giving the same partition?

Comment: What are combinations and how do they give partitions?

Comment: See a book on combinatorics for that. I don't think that the reader not familiar with these structures, will gain mauch from an explantion here.

Comment: I asked because I did not realize you were talking about integer compositions (you use the term "combination"). If you'd defined the term I would have realized your error sooner. In any case, sometimes readers do benefit from learning the background behind a question, even if they won't be able to answer it, if only for the simple reason of piquing curiosity.

Comment: It's funner to solve problems yourself, but if you're strapped for time and resources and all that, here's the solution: let $\lambda_i$ ($1\le i\le n$) be the multiplicity of $i$ in $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$. Then the number of compositions with this shape is $$\frac{n!}{\lambda_1!\lambda_2!\cdots\lambda_n!}.$$

Comment: Thanks, but there is an error in this expression,I guess. Lets say $n=5$, and we consider the partition $(2,3)$. Then there are two compositions giving this partition while your expressions says there are 120, since $\frac{5!}{0!1!1!0!0!}=5!$... Should it be $\frac{k!}{\lambda_1!\cdots\lambda_k!}$ instead?

Comment: Sorry, correction: the number of compositions $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$ is $$\frac{k!}{\lambda_1!\cdots\lambda_r!}$$ where the $\lambda_i$s are the multiplicities of the $n_i$s.

Comment: Ah? What is $r$?

Comment: However many multiplicities you need to talk about!

Comment: So we can choose $r=k$ if we use $0!=1$ to include zero multiplicities.

Comment: Yes. For example if $n=7$ and the partition is $(2,2,1,1,1)$ then there are $k=5$ coordinates, the multiplicities are $2$ and $3$, and so the number of relevant compositions is $\frac{5!}{2!3!}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My favorite way to count things is using group actions. They exploit inherent symmetry in a given combinatorial situation. One basic setup is a first attempt at counting some type of object, followed by a correction that takes into account how much the initial attempt overcounted (the extent to which the initial attempt overcounted being a product of symmetry). Often I'd wager one can put arguments using the language of group actions into more elementary language albeit less elegant.

In any case, here is how the argument would go using group actions. The symmetric group $S_k$ acts on the space of compositions of fixed shape $(n_1,\cdots,n_k)$: the action simply permutes the coordinates. This space is a single orbit. The stabilizer of any chosen composition is a copy of the direct product $S_{\lambda_1}\times\cdots\times S_{\lambda_r}$ inside $S_k$, where the $\lambda_i$s are the multiplicities of the $n_i$s. From here we need only employ the handy-dandy orbit-stabilizer theorem to compute the size of the orbit.

Comment: Credits go to anon since he gave the correct answer in an comment above

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  You are asking how many ways there are to put $n_1,n_2,\dots,n_k$ in order.  If they were all distinct, there would be $k!$ ways.  If $n_1=n_2=n_3$ and all the rest are distinct, how many different orders are there?  Clearly all the rest of the numbers have to stay put.  Can you generalize this?

Comment: I'm a little confused. With *hint* do you you mean, that you don't have a closed expression and just some idea on how to get there, or is it on stackexchange now common to encurrage the question-poster to answers his own questions?

Comment: @Mark With basic enough questions (relatively speaking to both the OP, at least according to outsider perception, and the writers themselves), yes, it is encouraged to help guide OPs in answering their own questions instead of doing all the work for them.

Comment: @MarkNeuhaus:  There are different styles.  When the question seems this simple, and some leading will get OP there, I try to help them see the way, rather than giving a full answer.  If it is a problem that I find fun, I may well give the full answer.  In this case, yes, I have a full answer and if OP engages we often get there.

Comment: Combinatorics is not my main field of research and I'm much more productive, if I don't have to bother with stuff I'm not an expert in. Why affort time into something, that already has a solution? Reinwenting the wheel only makes sense, if the purpose is to train students or so. .. So I seriously have to look elsewhere?